# modify text file in place (read and write text file)

Tags: python, file, io

I came across a weird behavior of `file.readlines()` and `file.writelines()` in python when I try to modify one of my text files. Could you please help me understand this unexpected behavior?  It really confuses me a lot.

Here is a simplistic example, which can be used to reproduce the weird behavior:
I know I can modify a text by reading its content, changing it, and writing to a text with 2 context managers like **method 1** below, it works very well and is very robust (I always get what I expect):

**method 1**

```
with open("sample.txt","r")as file:
    content = file.readlines()
    content[0] = "a = 1\n"
    content[2] = "v = 3\n"
    content[3] = "v\n"

with open("sample.txt","w")as file:
    file.writelines(content)
```

**sample.txt**:

```
a = -1

v = -3
vv

abc

c=1
```

**output file**:

```
a = 1

v = 3
v

abc

c=1
```

However, I try to save some effort to type and follow "DRY" principle. I used the following code instead (I believe I saw it somewhere on stack overflow). It really surprised me and caused some pain to locate this issue. It sometimes works well, sometime it does not depending on the text file.

**method 2**

```
with open("sample.txt","r+")as file:
    content = file.readlines()
    content[0] = "a = 1\n"
    content[2] = "v = 3\n"
    content[3] = "v\n"
    file.seek(0)
    file.writelines(content)
```

with the same input text file, it outputs the following text file:

```
a = 1

v = 3
v

abc

c=1
=1
```

I am extremely curious about the last line `=1` in the output text file by method 2, except that line, everything seems to be right. Could you explain that line came into being?

**Update**

We still can do text file modification in place with a single context manager, but to avoid the remnants from the existing file, we need to seek to the beginning of the file and truncate it completely.

```
with open("sample.txt","r+")as file:
    content = file.readlines()
    content[0] = "a = 1\n"
    content[2] = "v = 3\n"
    content[3] = "v\n"
    file.seek(0)
    file.truncate(0)
    file.writelines(content)
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: modify content in some specific lines

Comment: @python_user could you please explain why method 2 failed, sarcastically it works sometimes as well

Comment: for what purpose?

Comment: @anon01    the text file will serve as a template for another program, but I need to modify its content accordingly on the fly

Comment: ok :)  This is not the best way to go about this.  I'll provide an answer in a second with a suggestion

Comment: I am extremely curious about the last line in the output text file by method 2, except that line, everything seems to be right.

Comment: Took a look, not sure exactly.  In any case, you are better off using `yaml` or `configparser` for reading/writing human readable config files, pickle or json for more complex.  The benefit is that variable modification happens inside python so you don't end up with corrupted state (such as the invalid `=1` line)

Comment: also, python_user is right: Taking the DRY principle to the extreme results in something like codegolf; unreadable, dense code.  Your original implementation would be preferred by any experienced python programmer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you open the file in `r+` mode and seek back to the beginning, you are overwriting bytes starting at that position, but the bytes *after* that position will not be replaced.

The `=1` you see are the remnants of the old contents, after you replaced the beginning of the file with a shorter string than what it used to contain before.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be the remnant when the new content has fewer bytes than old content. I guess we still use method 2 by adding ````truncate()```` to the file handler. I guess I am  just unwilling to use two context managers to do something which can be achieved by one already. See my updates.